# apt-get в Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

Недавно начал работать c Ubuntu и не совсем понимаю процесс установки пакетов, а именно, при такой команде `apt-get install nginx`, откуда он начинает качать данные пакет? Если я правильно с репозитория?

Answer (score 3):

Команда `apt-get update` позволяет обновить доступные приложения из всех репозиториев которые вы добавили.

Отвечая на ваш вопрос: команда `apt-get install nginx` найдет репозиторий в котором будет нужный вам пакет и скачает его для последующей установки.

Собственно посмотреть доступные вам репозитории вы можете в

> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

Comment: Понял.то есть если мне надо будет установить какой то пакет  а репозиторий для него не подключен,мне сперва придется его подключить и уже после вызывать команду install?

Comment: @q Да, вы абсолютно правы

Comment: @quaresma89 Да, вы абсолютно правы. И прошу прощения за верхний комментарий, не нашел как его можно исправить.

Comment: исправьте, пожалуйта, ошибки: 1. `apt-get update` обновляет не «приложения», и даже не пакеты, а всего лишь **списки** пакетов. 2. доступные репозитории перечислены в файлах `/etc/apt/sources.list` и `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`

Answer (score 1):

Да, именно с репозитория пакетов, к которым разрешено обращение. Разрешения устанавливаются в настройках apt-get:  Ubuntu всё программное обеспечение делится на четыре секции, называемые компонентами, чтобы отразить разницу в лицензии и уровне доступной поддержки.
Пакеты распределяются по компонентам таким образом:

```
Main – свободное ПО, официально поддерживаемое компанией Canonical.
Restricted – проприетарное ПО (в основном — драйверы устройств), официально поддерживаемое компанией Canonical.
Universe – свободное ПО, официально не поддерживаемое компанией Canonical (но поддерживаемое сообществом пользователей).
Multiverse – проприетарное ПО, не поддерживаемое компанией Canonical.
```

Существует четыре основных репозитория Ubuntu.

```
$release1) – это пакеты на момент выхода релиза.
$release-security – пакеты критических обновлений безопасности.
$release-updates – пакеты обновления системы (т.е. более поздние версии ПО, вышедшие уже после релиза).
$release-backports – бэкпорты более новых версий некоторого ПО, которое доступно только в нестабильных версиях Ubuntu.
partner – репозиторий содержищий ПО компаний-партнеров Canonical.
```